# How i can round this number 5.53 always like this: 5.55 in PHP?

Tags: php, rounding, floor, ceil

I want to round number 5.53 always like this: 5.55  in PHP ?

Any idea?

Comment: If the linked question does not help, please share your approaches

Comment: Use round() function
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php